# Which version of Xcode is compatible with OS X Lion 10.7.1?

Tags: xcode, osx-lion

I have purchased a Mac notebook which has Mac OS X Lion 10.7.1. Now I want to develop iPhone apps so I want to know which Xcode version is supported on it that has storyboards facility.

Answer (score 5):

Just get the latest version from the [App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/hu/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12). It supports Storyboards and is compatible with Lion.

Comment: Also note that storyboards are only supported in iOS 5, not previous versions of iOS.

Comment: I have download xcode 4.3.1 but it not support on it. It require 10.7.3 Mac OSx Lion but I have 10.7.1

Comment: @user1652551 What's wrong with updating from 10.7.1 to 10.7.3?

Comment: I have try but it'll always stop downloading after 84%. So can you gave any suggestion for 10.7.1

Comment: @user1652551 I'd recommend finding out why your update is failing, rather than deliberately sticking with an out-of-date OS - you could try asking at superuser.com or askdifferent.com if you continue to have trouble.

Comment: What @Tim said;  if your system is failing to update, for any reason, it may likely be because your system is hosed.   For **any machine purchased** used, I would **always** re-format and re-install the OS.  **Always**.  You have no idea what nonsense nastiness has been left behind on the system.

Answer (score 1):

If you must stay at Lion 10.7.1, try the first developer tool releases for Lion (Xcode 4.2, or 4.2.1) available [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=Xcode%204%2E2)